# How to correctly handle 3rd party POD

Tags: c++, data-structures, wrapper

I am using a 3rd party library that is for the most part consists of POD structures. Even more, those structures are shared pointed by a special library pointer, build with a special library factory, so they come and go around in the form of `Ptr<APod>`. Since PODs are by definition all public, this has led them to be modified all around the code base, scattering the code everywhere. I am trying to find a better approach. I would like to wrap them in order to make them become real classes, so that every operation regarding those data are forced to be inside the wrapper class:

```
class Wrapper
{
public:
    Wrapper( /* params to correcly build APod */ );

    /** required when it needs to be sent back to the library **/
    const Ptr<APod>& unwrap() const;
private:
    Ptr<APod> m_data;
};
```

But even if this is fine for most of the library PODs, it is a little bit tricky when PODs have fields that consist of other POD, or when there is a collection of PODs (the library also have its own Vector of Ptr to PODs). Another tricky thing is that since the library accepts back only `const Ptr<APod>&`, which means constant pointer to non-constant object, my `unwrap()` method is still allowing programmers to have too much freedom on these PODs.
Can my approach be improved? Or is it entirely wrong, and should be replaced with another approach?

Answer (score 0):

If some of the PODs can be included in other PODs or in array/containers, it means that you should never try to build the POD yourself, but just assume that you build your wrapper from a pointer to POD or in the case of your specific library a `Ptr<APod>`.

Without knowing the semantics of `Ptr` (unique/shared/weak) I cannot say whether you should then keep a copy of the original `Ptr<APod>` or a reference to it.

Comment: The behaviour is the same as a shared pointer, but it is done by the library, it is not the STL one but it is pretty similar. The factory provided by the library can build pointers or array of pointers. I can wrap also a full array of PODs, but sometimes other PODs have a field that is a single POD element and that remain unwrapped if I do so. In general, what could be a right way to achieve information hiding and encapsulation having so many PODs all around?

Comment: Ideally I would like that only the wrapper classes are aware of the Factory and know how to use it, as well as they know how to deal with the specific POD data type.

Comment: @nyarlathotep108: wrapping a complex library can be complex... Maybe you could build a [mcve] demonstrating the problem with a stub library. You will probably have to explicitely process all the functions of the factory, but I cannot say more without an example.

Comment: The problem I see is that every data in input/output from/to this library is a POD, and this lead our codebase to be able to modify these data everywhere because data is just public.